# How to create accordion with all sections inactive by default?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, accordion

I need to create an accordion where all sections must be inactive on load and will only be activated when clicked.

Reading the documentation I saw that the first section will always be active by default.

> Expands the specified accordion sections. Pass in a string or list of section names. Section names are case-sensitive. **The first section in the accordion is expanded by default.** To support multiple active sections, set allowMultipleSectionsOpen to true.

How could I create an accordion with all sections inactive when loading?

This is bothering me because I want to call a function only when a section is clicked and I'm trying to use the *onsectiontoggle* attribute, but it's always triggered when loading the accordion as there will always be an active section, the first one.

> onsectiontoggle
> Fired when the accordion loads with at **least one active section** or when a section is toggled. Returns the openSections parameter containing an array of strings for the active section names.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify `allowMultipleSectionsOpen=true`, then the component defaults to no open sections, and you won't get the initial `onsectiontoggle` event. You can always choose to toggle `allowMultipleSectionsOpen` on the first `onsectiontoggle` if you want to keep one accordion element open after the initial event.

---

## Example

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <lightning:accordion allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true">
        <lightning:accordionSection name="Section1" label="Section 1">
            Section 1 Content
        </lightning:accordionSection>
        <lightning:accordionSection name="Section2" label="Section 2">
            Section 2 Content
        </lightning:accordionSection>
    </lightning:accordion>
</aura:application>
```

Comment: I've tried this way but the onsectiontoggle keeps running when the accordion is initially loaded.
 
<lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion" allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true" onsectiontoggle="{!c.displayOtherField}">

Comment: @MarcusVinicius The documentation and behavior don't seem to match then? I'll do some research on that.